# In Google Webmaster tools, where should you submit a sitemap that contains multiple subdomains?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I work on a site which is structured en.site.com however the site contains subdomains for all its products like product1.en.site.com The sitemap contains all the products on all the subdomains. The problem is that each subdomain in Google Webmaster Tools you need to create a property thus submitting a small sitemap for each property for each product would be impossible. Is it ok to submit the whole site under en.site.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sadly you must:*

- Add each sub domain as a new property to Google Search Console.
- Add each separate sitemap to each new property within Google Search Console.

It should be noted that you do not need a sitemap for Google to crawl sites, nor does it speed up the process, as long as your site is search engine friendly then the bots will have no issues indexing your content.

However... there is a benefit of adding sub domains to Google Search Console, primarily because you will receive notifications and insights.

Comment: The site I am working on has 100,000 products so adding 100,000 subdomains is unworkable. Would Google still process subdomains that are in the main sitemap?  Or when you say "Sadly you must", you really mean "Sadly you must".

Comment: You can only use internal site maps, Google considers a sub domain as external. This question has been asked before in various forms and I've just closed it linking to another which you may find useful.